# How to add klavika as a font family?

Tags: fonts

In regular LaTeX, is it possible to add `klavika` font type? For example using `\fontfamily{...}`? Are there specific packages which need to be loaded?

My main goal is to create a command where the word Facebook is written in the Facebook font, `klavika`. I wrote this line:

```
\newcommand{\Facebook}{\fontfamily{qtm}{\textbf{facebook }}}
```

which works but with `TeX Gyre Termes - {qtm}`

[image]

Any ideas?

Edit: The code and the screenshot

Comment: do you have the font? in which format?

Comment: No, I don't have it and I was not able to find it.

Comment: Unrelated to the question itself, but I seriously doubt that the code you wrote works: there is no `\selectfont` and the group around the word `facebook` is also not quite right...

Comment: "klavika font" gives tons of hits. If you found/bought a suitable ttf or otf version you can use it with lualatex or xelatex.

Comment: @campa I edited the code and added a screenshot of the results.

Comment: Well, that's quite a different code...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what do you mean with tons of hits?

Comment: In a internet search of your choice ...

Comment: When you followed Ulrikes advice you should be led to the website of [Process Type Foundry](https://processtypefoundry.com/fonts/klavika/) where you can buy the font but since 2015 Facebook uses a custom font for the logo.

Comment: `fontspec` ((to be used with `xelatex` or `lualatex`) has a `\newfontfamily` command, which can be used with any  .otf or .ttf font family installed on your computer. If you want to use it with `pdflatex`, it is more complex: you'll have to create `.tfm`s and`.vf`s with the `lcdftypetools` first. A good documentation for the latter case is Philipp Lehman's *Font Installation Guide*.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I didn't really think that I'd have to buy `klavika`. But apparently it's the only way to get it (as far as my search went). So I'm switching to use a free alternative which I found [here](https://www.fontsc.com/font/alternatives/klavika). I'm going with the `Titillium Web`. This font is available on [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)